# Calculating relative frequency of each word occurring in a list by comparing it with other list

Tags: python

I have a list of list of elements in which I want to create a relative frequency of elements by comparing it with elements of another list.

For example:

```
A = [['a','b','c'],['b','d'],['c','d','e'],['a','c','e','f']]
B = [['a','b','c'],['c','e'],['c','e']]
C = [['b','c','e'],['b','c','e','g']]
```

I want to calculate two different values (X and Y) for each word appearing in all the lists and take their ratio and finally store that ratio at that word with the same list name.
The way X and Y will be calculated are:
For word 'a' in A:

```
X = Number of lists it is appearing in A / Total number of lists in A
Y = Sum of number of times it is appearing in rest of the list / sum of total length of remaining list
```

For Example: For 'a' in A:

```
X = 2/4 = 0.5
Y = 1/5 = 0.2
```

And finally take ratio of X/Y or Y/X whichever is greater than 1 and store it. The same thing I have to do for every element.

Kindly help how this can be done.

Comment: well defined, but i'd like to see your effort.

Comment: I am very new to python, so i am not able to think how to start solving this problem.

Comment: Can you explain how you calculate `Y = 1/5 = 0.2`?

Comment: Not sure how you are calculating `Y`

Comment: For Y, consider 'a' in A. It is appearing only 1 times in B and C combined list of length 3+2 = 5, so Y = 1/5 = 0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this snippet will give you agood start:

first getting all unique words in all lists:

```
all_words = set().union(*A).union(*B).union(*C)
```

calculating the length of each list of lists:

```
length_A = float(len(A))
num_rest_lists = float(len(B) + len(C))
```

for each word calculating the ratio as you mentioned:

```
res_dict = {]
for word in all_words:
    X = sum(map(lambda x: word in x, A))/length_A
    Y =  sum(map(lambda x: word in x, B)) + sum(map(lambda x: word in x, C))/num_rest_lists
    if Y == 0 or X == 0:
        print "word: %s, X: %s, Y: %s" % (word, X,Y)
        res_dict[word] = 0
    elif X/float(Y) > 1 :
        print "word: %s, ratio: %s" % (word, X/float(Y))
        res_dict[word] = X/float(Y)
    else:
        print "word: %s, ratio: %s" % (word, Y/float(X))
        res_dict[word] = Y/float(X)
```

print res_dict

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the above solution. If I want to store the value of X/Y or Y/X for each element in the same list i.e. A,B or C, how will i do that?

Comment: Can you give an example for how you would like to store them?

Comment: I want to store them in the form of a dictionary where besides every element I can store the calculated ratio so that whenever I want to filter out any particular ratio words, I can directly do that.

Comment: I updated the answer, to show how this could be done.